Android App Crashes From java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
I am creating an app with Android Studio that crashes when I run it on my OnePlus N200 5G device. The name of the package is com.example.chapter3.
Android Application/Library Version: 8.0.2
OnePlus N200 5G Version: 12
Kotlin Version: 1.7.2
The code is below in a MainActivity.kt file:
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    var count by remember() { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(
        modifier=Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ){
        Text(text = "Counter: $count", style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge)
        Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = { count++ }) {
            Text("Increment")
        }
    }
}

The manifest is below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Chapter3"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Chapter3">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

The errors from the logcat are below:
Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.chapter3/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dm': No such file or directory
Unable to open '/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/base.dm': No such file or directory
Unable to open '/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/base.dm': No such file or directory

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chapter3, PID: 15473
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chapter3/com.example.chapter3.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chapter3.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.chapter3/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3682)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2345)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chapter3.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.chapter3/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~-viv8utqhkYTZoznAoSHqA==/com.example.chapter3-XWzS_aPEYxw4grWM96M0Pw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2345) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034) 

After reading similar posts,

I do not understand what a MultiDex is, nor whether it is relevant to this error
I put the MainActivity file in the manifest, so I am not sure why the system does not see it
I do not know why the ziparchive cannot open the said files and whether that is relevant to this error

I lack a lot of the context for this and the textbook I am using has absolutely no information on the issues I am facing. Please help me contextualize this.

What's the package of your MainActivity?

@Leviathan The name of the package is com.example.chapter3. Post edited accordingly.

Your edit suggests that com.example.chapter3 is the package of your app. What I meant is the first line in your MainActivity.kt file. It may very well be the same, but your edit didn't make that clear.

The first line in my Main activity.kt file is import android.os.Bundle

It should be this: package com.example.chapter3 -- Your app cannot compile without the package information. Will you please have another look?

@Leviathan I see. Apologies, I'm going straight out of a textbook and it didn't include that. I'll see if it works

I just checked, apparently it isn't a compile error right away if the package information is missing. Curious. But you should definitely put every class explicitly in a package with package as the first line of each file. And your MainActivity should be in com.example.chapter3.
